# How to find the duplicate salary

Tags: sql

I'm doing like this :

```
SELECT salary COUNT(salary ) AS NumberOfTimes
FROM person
GROUP BY salary   
HAVING (COUNT(salary) > 1)
```

Comment: And what is the question? If it exists a better way to do ? If so, no your query is great. (Just a "," missing)

Comment: You're grouping agregated field. Does it work at all?

Comment: @Mitch: The query seems to be looking for people with the same salary, not a person with multiple identical salaries.

Comment: When asking this kind of question, there are some basics to include: What you expect to see, and what you're seeing instead. Ideally with some sample data. I've answered the actual question you've asked, and yet, I suspect it doesn't help solve your actual problem. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Other than a missing comma after the first `salary`, what you have is fine. You don't need the parentheses around your `HAVING` clause, but I can't imagine the parser cares:

```
SELECT salary, COUNT(salary) AS NumberOfTimes
FROM person
GROUP BY salary
HAVING COUNT(salary) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma between "salary" and "COUNT(salary)".